# Gathering multiple time measures in one sampler

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to gather multiple samples during one sampler run.

My scenario (assuming that it's possible):

```
Start sample [1]
      var page = LoadPage('www.foo.bar')
Stop sample [1]
      page.ClickButton
Start sample [2]
      page.WaitUntillActoinIsPerformed()
Stop sample [2]
```

It would be enough to have those times in csv report but if it's possible to have one in HTML one, I think I'll survive that as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your samplers under [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) like:

- Transaction Controller

  - Sampler 1
  - Sampler 2

This way you will get both individual samplers response times and one more "artificial" sampler having cumulative stats for all samplers in its [scope](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules).

[image: JMeter Transaction Controller in Action]

More information: [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)